# How to use Cairo PNGs in R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr, cairo

There are many advantages to using Cairo to save R graphics ([see here, for example](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2017/09/27/working-with-r-cairo-graphics-custom-fonts-and-ggplot/)). When saving PDFs, for instance, the `cairo_pdf` device correctly embeds custom fonts.

Using the `cairo_pdf` graphics device is easy with ggplot-based graphics with `ggsave()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ugly_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Some data about cars") +
  theme_gray(base_family = "Papyrus")
ugly_plot

ggsave(ugly_plot, filename = "ugly_plot.pdf", 
       width = 4, height = 2.5, device = cairo_pdf)
```

Using the `cairo_pdf` device in R Markdown with knitr is also easy—add `dev: cairo_pdf` to the YAML front matter:

````r
---
title: "Cairo stuff"
output:
  pdf_document:
    dev: cairo_pdf
---

```{r make-ugly-plot, fig.width=4, fig.height=2.5}
library(ggplot2)

ugly_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Some data about cars") +
  theme_gray(base_family = "Papyrus")
ugly_plot
```
````

[image: PDF output]

There are also advantages to using Cairo-based PNGs, since [Cairo correctly deals with DPI](http://gforge.se/2013/02/exporting-nice-plots-in-r/#update). If you place a normally-saved PNG with a high DPI into a Word or PowerPoint file, the dimensions of the figure are exaggerated and not accurate. If you place a Cairo-based PNG with the same high DPI into Word, the dimensions are correct:

[image: Weird Word dimensions]

Saving ggplot output as high resolution Cairo PNGs is easy with `ggsave()`, but the syntax is slightly different from saving as Cairo PDFs. Instead of specifying a device, we specify type:

```r
ggsave(ugly_plot, filename = "ugly_plot.png", 
       width = 4, height = 2.5, dpi = 300, type = "cairo")
```

Placing that file in Word or PowerPoint works great and everything is sized correctly at high resolution.

This misinterpretation of dimensions carries over into R Markdown when knitting to HTML or Word. It'd be great to have knitr use `type = "cairo"` when knitting, but replicating this `dpi = 300, type = "cairo"` in R Markdown, however, is more difficult. The Cairo library includes devices like `Cairo::CairoPNG()`, but `ggsave(..., type = "cairo")` doesn't use this device. It uses R's standard PNG device, but with Cairo support turned on.

Making the figure high resolution is easy enough with adding `dpi=300` to the chunk options, but I can't get knitr to use the built-in PNG device with `type = cairo` enabled. I tried naively adding `type: cairo` to the YAML metadata, but it unsurprisingly doesn't work. The PNG that knitr generates doesn't use Cairo and is much larger than expected (and is gigantic in HTML and Word documents).

````r
---
title: "Cairo stuff"
output:
  html_document: 
    self_contained: no  # to see resulting figure as a file
    dev: png
    type: cairo  # this doesn't do anything
---

```{r make-ugly-plot, fig.width=5, fig.height=3.5, dpi=300}
library(ggplot2)

ugly_plot <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Some data about cars") +
  theme_gray(base_family = "Papyrus")
ugly_plot
```
````

---

In sum, I'm looking for a way to use the same output you'd get from `ggsave(..., filename = "blah.png", dpi = 300, type = "cairo")` in knitr. Is there a way to do this?

```r
---
title: "Something"
output:
  pdf_document:
    dev: cairo_pdf  # yay Cairo output
  html_document:  # What needs to go here?
    dev: png
    type: cairo
---
```

Comment: Is it maybe due to something to do with `dev.args` instead of just `dev` , as in my answer below??

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `knitr` options, not the YAML header.

You can use `knitr` options to change the type of a specific device (Yihui's recommendation):

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev.args = list(png = list(type = "cairo")))
```

Alternately, you could do it conditionally based on the output:

```
if (!knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(dpi = 300, dev.args = list(type = "cairo"))
})
```

I've used this on a couple of documents now. **Note**: I've only used this for documents doing `rmarkdown::render(...)` from the R command line.

Comment: Ah! Good call! I didn't know about the `dev.args` list thing!

Comment: Yeah, it's really useful. I don't know if / how that translates to an option in the yaml header

Comment: Also, instead of using `knitr::opts_knit$get...`, which will fail with an error when running interactively, you can use `if (!knitr::is_latex_output()) { ... }`, which works fine interactively

Comment: I recommend using `dev.args = list(png  = list(type = "cairo"))`, i.e. apply `type = "cairo"` to the `png` device only, without affecting other graphical devices.

Comment: Oops. I had a typo. I meant `png` instead of `cairo_pdf`. I just corrected my comment.

Comment: Wait, so you could get rid of the conditional test and just set that in the `knitr::opts_chunk`?? Will have to try that.

Comment: Yes, you can :)

Comment: OK, has something changed in knitr in the latest version? When I try and recreate this post http://rmflight.github.io/post/nicer-png-graphics/ with the latest version of knitr, *all* the graphics look good ...., the basic one doesn't look horrible anymore.

Comment: I don't recall any changes related to graphical devices in **knitr** recently. Note that `type = "cairo"` is actually the default of `png()` if `capabilities('cairo') == TRUE`, so I'm actually surprised that this option helped at all...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to [@rmflight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55009461/435004) using a piece of code at the top of each file, this can be achieved in the shell wrapper or `Makefile` that knits Rmarkdown files using the optional parameters to `rmarkdown::render()`:

```
R -e 'rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", "pdf_document", output_file="foo.pdf", runtime = "static", output_options = list(dpi = 300, dev.args = list(type = "cairo")))'
```