# knitr generating errors in document but generates figures correctly regardless

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm knitting an R Markdown file on macOS and I'm using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = c("png", "cairo_pdf"))` to save the output of plots as PNG and PDF files simultaneously. I'm also using the Cairo PDF library since it can embed fonts correctly by default (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009313/how-to-use-cairo-pngs-in-r-markdown))

When I knit and create a plot that uses a custom font, knitr correctly saves both the PNG and PDF files using Cairo:

[image: figure output]

However, in the actual knitted R Markdown document, R complains about missing fonts and provides dozens of warnings. This is odd, since it is working just fine behind the scenes.

Here's a MWE:

````
---
title: "So many warnings?"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "fig/",  # Save images to a subdirectory
                      echo = FALSE,  # Hide code for now
                      dpi = 300,  # High resolution PNGs
                      # Save all figures as Cairo PDFs and PNGs
                      dev = c("png", "cairo_pdf"),
                      dev.args = list(png = list(type = "cairo")))
```

```{r load-libraries}
library(ggplot2)
```

```{r warningless-plot}
# This will save two files in the fig/ folder, both saved using Cairo:
# - fig/warningless-plot-1.png
# - fig/warningless-plot-1.pdf

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```

```{r warningful-plot}
# This will save two files in the fig/ folder, both saved *correctly* using Cairo:
# - fig/warningful-plot-1.png
# - fig/warningful-plot-1.pdf

# However, rmarkdown or knitr or something in the pipeline gets mad and throws 
# a ton of warnings.

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_grey(base_family = "Comic Sans MS")
```
````

The figures themselves are saved correctly, but the HTML output is full of these warnings:

```
## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
## font family 'Comic Sans MS' not found in PostScript font database

## Warning in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :    
## font family 'Comic Sans MS' not found in PostScript font database
```

Right now my solution is to add `warning=FALSE` to the chunk options for `warningful-plot` and all other chunks that generate plots with custom fonts. I'd like to know why these extra warnings are happening, though, and if there's a way to avoid getting warnings in the first place.

Comment: It seems that this may be a more widespread issue? https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/729

Comment: And another place where it crops up: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes/issues/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question here…

According to a couple issues on GitHub (at [knitr](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/729) and [hrbrthemes](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/hrbrthemes/issues/2)), this happens because knitr invisibly uses a null PDF device (`pdf(NULL)`) in the background when actually knitting. The default `pdf()` graphics device in R can't handle custom fonts, though, hence the warnings. Even though none of the visible graphics ever go through the base `pdf()` device, they still go through it invisibly I guess.

When knitting using `dev = 'png'`, knitr will use an invisible `png()` device and no warnings will be thrown. It seems that using a `cairo_pdf` device at the same time breaks this and forces knitr to go back to an invisible, custom-font-less `pdf()` device.

We can fix this by forcing knitr to use an invisible `png()` device instead, [based on this comment here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/729#issuecomment-40336104):

```
# Use invisible NULL png() device
options(device = function(file, width, height) {
  png(tempfile(), width = width, height = height)
})

# knit options, including `dev = c("png", "cairo_pdf")`
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = "fig/",  # Save images to a subdirectory
                      echo = FALSE,  # Hide code for now
                      dpi = 300,  # High resolution PNGs
                      # Save all figures as Cairo PDFs and PNGs
                      dev = c("png", "cairo_pdf"),
                      dev.args = list(png = list(type = "cairo")))
```

That `options(device = ...)` incantation makes the warnings go away.