# How to improve plot quality in a RMarkdown html_document()?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

Every time I want to knit a html document, the plot quality isn't great. Is there a way to change the rendering engine in RStudio and produce better plotting?

I'm using RStudio v. 1.4 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to increase the resolution for all graphics, you can set the chunk option dpi parameter at the beginning of your Rmd:

````
   ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dpi=300)
````

Alternatively, you can selectively increase the dpi as part of the chunk options

````
    ```{r myplot, dpi = 300 ....}
````

Check out your results. The setting of dpi will also have an impact on the size of your labels/characters and you may want to resize them.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't solve my problem. I've found this piece of code in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009313/how-to-use-cairo-pngs-in-r-markdown):

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev.args = list(png = list(type = "cairo")))`